# Why am I getting a MySQL error?

Tags: mysql, sql

Here is my query. Its intention is allow access to properties of the `animals` that constitute a match of two animals.

The match table contains columns for animal1ID and animal2ID to store which animals constitute the match.

```
SELECT id, 
    (SELECT * 
    FROM animals 
    WHERE animals.id=matches.animal1ID) AS animal1, 

    (SELECT * 
    FROM users 
    WHERE animals.id=matches.animalID) AS animal2 
FROM matches WHERE id=5
```

However, MySQl returns this error: `Operand should contain 1 column(s)`.

Why? Is there an alternative way to do this, perhaps with a JOIN statement?

Comment: query makes no sense ...

Comment: I think your sub queries should return a specific column and not the complete row

Comment: ? why? I'm basically trying to access the name of both animals of the match and return them as properties with this SQL statement.

Comment: Why JOIN over SELECT statements with aliases?

Comment: @Alon +1 This is the immediate issue here.

Comment: "SELECT * ..." is returning more than one column.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should not use * in subqueries in SELECT clause. Rewrite your query in this way:

```
SELECT m.id, a1.*, a2.*
FROM matches as m
LEFT JOIN animals as a1
    on a1.id=m.animal1ID 
LEFT JOIN users as a2
    on a2.id=m.animalID
WHERE m.id=5
```

Or, just replace * with single column name. But, in this case you must be sure that your subquery will always return only one row.

Also you can use aliases to separate the fields in the way like this:

```
SELECT m.id, a1.name as an1_name, a2.name as a2_name, a1.some_field as blabla ...
```

And you can compare the results of your query prior to getting it in PHP, just add something like this in WHERE clause:

```
...
WHERE m.id=5 
    AND a1.name <> a2.name    -- or what you want
```

Comment: Wow, thank you. What if the field values for the two rows of animals collide? For instance, both animals have names, and I want to later access the names of both animals in a PHP object.

Comment: Not sure, what you mean. Can you provide more details or sample data? Anyway, you can work with the returned rows in any way you want.

Comment: I did a little update to show how to use fields aliases in the query. Hope it hepls.

Answer (score 2):

How about something more like this:

```
SELECT id, 
 animals.*, 
 users.* 
FROM matches 
    JOIN animals 
        ON animals.id=matches.animal1ID
    JOIN users 
        ON users.id=matches.animalID
WHERE id=5
```

If `animals` or `users` are not guaranteed, you can use a `LEFT JOIN`

```
SELECT id, 
 animals.*, 
 users.* 
FROM matches 
    LEFT JOIN animals 
        ON animals.id=matches.animal1ID
    LEFT JOIN users 
        ON users.id=matches.animalID
WHERE id=5
```

With these JOINS, you can pick whatever column you need from `animals` and `users`

```
SELECT id, 
 animals.animalName AS AnimalName, 
 users.animalName AS UserAnimalName
FROM matches 
    (LEFT) JOIN animals 
        ON animals.id=matches.animal1ID
    (LEFT) JOIN users 
        ON users.id=matches.animalID
WHERE id=5
```

Comment: Wow, thank you. What if the field values for the two rows of animals collide? For instance, both animals have names, and I want to later access the names of both animals in a PHP object.

Comment: @JohnHoffman If they have there own unique identifier, then you can (and should) use that instead of text